# Envio de Email SMTP

Tags: php, smtp

Estou fazendo o envio e está indo como enviado, porém não recebo, o que pode ser?

```
<?
/Leitura dos dados de cadastro
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

//mensagem do email
$dados = "<br><b>Contato Recebido:</b>";
$dados .= "<br><br>Nome: ".$nome."";
$dados .= "<br><br>Empresa: ".$empresa."";
$dados .= "<br><br>Telefone: ".$telefone."";
$dados .= "<br><br>Email: ".$email."";
$dados .= "<br><br>Mensagem: ".$mensagem."<br>";

//requisicao para phpmailer
if (!class_exists("phpmailer")) 
{
    require("PHPMailer-5.2.6/class.phpmailer.php");
}

 // Inicia a classe PHPMailer
 $mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); //  Define que a mensagem será enviada via servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Ativa a autenticação
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Host = 'mail.meudominio.com.br'; //endereço do servidor smtp
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "vendas@meudominio.com.br"; 
$mail->Password = "senha";

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->Subject = "Contato";  
$mail->MsgHTML($dados);
$address = "exemplo@gmail.com"; 
$mail->AddAddress($address, "nome");


//envia
if($mail->Send())
{
    echo "enviado"; 
}else{ echo "erro"; }
?>
```

Comment: Verificou o lixo eletrônico? O endereço `$address = "exemplo@gmail.com"; ` está correto? Está testando em algum host ou localmente? Adicione o máximo de detalhes importantes na pergunta.

Comment: não está no lixo eletrônico. estou testando localmente. 
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "nome"); está correto, já substituí por $mail->AddAddress("emaildestino");

Comment: Só uma pergunta pra desencargo de consciência, tentou trocar isto `<?` por isto `<?php`. Alguns servidores veem com o short_open_tag desabilitados.

Comment: Habilitou o _debug_ `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`, pra ver se algo acontece de diferente?

Comment: esse comentário em cima com uma barra não existe: `/Leitura dos dados de cadastro`, além disso o uso de `short_open_tag` é uma má pratica.

Comment: O `from` deve ser um email do seu dominio e não passado pelo usuário.

Comment: Seria bom você ver o erro no console do navegador, no Chrome por exemplo. Veja se tem algum erro.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se seu servidor está habilitado o envio via *SMTP*.

Para maior eficiência da dúvida, diga que tipo de servidor está usando.

Está usando em ambiente *Linux*? Está usando algum servidor de teste para *Windows* como *EasyPHP*, *XAAMP* ou semelhantes?

Com essas informações podemos ajudar melhor!

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda, o erro estava realmente no 'from', que estava recebendo um parâmetro errado.