# Envio de Email via SMTP

Tags: smtp

Implementei o envio de email em um formulário e quando testei localmente tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Recebi o email de forma correta. Na hora de atualizar no site e testar, o email nao é enviado. Qual pode ser o problema?

Como verifico se o servidor está habilitado para o envio via SMTP?

Comment: É o mesmo problema/código [dessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80230/envio-de-email-smtp)

Comment: Aquela ainda dá para responder, esta nem dá.